# Is the tagline area spam-bot proof?

Tags: spam

Is the tagline area spam-bot proof?

I've added my email address into the tagline area. Could spam bots pick it up?

You can see it here: http://richardclunan.com

(And if I add my email address into posts and pages, is it spam-bot proof there?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is found in the publicly accessible HTML of a website or page can be indexed by Search Engines, or spam bots. If you don't want a spam bot finding something, don't put it on a public page.

Answer (score 1):

Quite frankly I think we lost the war long ago on spammers GETTING our email addresses.  There are just too many ways that they get them and our friends just give them away too (naively and innocently of course).

I take the approach that it is more important to be easily contactable by those I need/want to contact me.

Then concentrate on good trapping and blocking of spam.

Gmail is pretty good actually - traps pretty much all spam/junk and only the very occasional false positive.  (I use my domain name with gmail and imap to local thunderbird for own backups so if gmail ever fails, I just work direct with my domain.)

I do a quick visual scan of the junk folder every day or so just in case we miss something important and to keep tabs on volume / type.

Actually it has not been so bad lately.  See http://www.kaspersky.com/au/news?id=207576320